# While will my following try/except code not work? It doesn't catch the HTTPError

Tags: python, http-error, try-except

I am trying to request weather api data and I can pull some of the data but eventually the code throws an `HTTPError` despite the `Try/Except` that I already have there. What am I writing wrong for my `Try/Except`?

I have tried to put the `HTTPError` in parentheses and catch is with `HTTPError` as he to give me back the error as a variable so I could read it. I've tried from `urllib.error` import `HTTPError`. Nothing works.

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError

for city in cities:
    current_city = owm.get_current(city, **settings)
    try:
        print(f'Current city is {current_city["name"]} and the city number is: {current_city["id"]}')
    except HTTPError:
           print("Ooops")

    print("------------")
```

Here is the error message:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Your try block does not include the call that raises the exception.

Comment: Move it one line below.

Comment: Move `current_city = owm.get_current(city, **settings)` inside the `try/catch`

Comment: Great, you can delete the question, otherwise it will be closed!